# IntelliJ IDEA not recognizing SQL dialect

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea, dialect

We use IntelliJ IDEA actively and we have our wrappers for work with DB (PostgreSQL). The thing is that when we use placeholders, SQL is stopped being highlighted.

"select * from " + schema + ".users where id = " + id + ";";

This code is not recognised as SQL, so highlighting doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You should be using `PreparedStatement` for doing SQL queries with parameters instead of concatenating strings to create an SQL statement, otherwise your code will likely be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection).

Comment: It is a Java file, there is no reason IntelliJ should recognize SQL in it. `select`, `from` and `where` could as well be java variables.

Comment: @Bentaye IntelliJ has many features that go beyond just parsing Java code. Normally it recognises SQL in strings and also syntax-highlights it. In this case it probably doesn't work because the SQL is not in a single string literal, but because Takhir is creating it by concatenating parts.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jesper, you should try using preparedStatements, not only would your Statements get more secure, also the problem which you are currently having should be solved by it.